# Soft Question: Textbook for first graduate course in Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I will be studying Functional Analysis for the first time, at the first-year grad school level.  My relevant background is $1$ basic course in Topology and $1$ basic course in Measure Theory.

I was given some recommendations for what textbooks may be suitable to a person in my position (sufficient detail to learn at the graduate level, but easy enough for a complete beginner to hit the ground running), and I now have to make a decision that will haunt me for a semester. My question is **Based on your experience, can you give me any insight into the pros and cons of any of these books**:

- W. Rudin, Functional Analysis
- G.K. Pedersen, Analysis Now
- R.J. Zimmer, Essential results of functional analysis
- J.B. Conway, A course in functional analysis
- C.D. Aliprantis, K. Border, Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide *(a comprehensive text, but don't feel intimidated)*
- B. Simon, Convexity: An analytic approach *(as you can guess by the title, not exactly what we are doing but this text is an excellent supplement)*

Comment: You should also consider Erwin Kreyszig's *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications*, which in my experience is more beginner-friendly than Rudin's and Pedersen's texts.

Comment: *Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces* by Weidmann is good. Rudin is always good, it's an industry standard, but it can sometimes feel a touch dated. I especially like Rudin's geometry/convexity arguments, found them approachable and intuitive. Also consider Royden/Fitzpatrick's *Real Analysis*; there is a huge chunk concerning analysis on linear spaces. I like the problems in this book and the exposition, proofs are very readable. It does ignore complex spaces, but the differences aren't much cause for concern in the general theory.

Comment: Overall my opinion is that you're not going to see *a ton* of variation in the way these authors treat the general theoretical framework. If you want to find which book you prefer, look to chapters 4,5,6... beyond the setup to see which topics the authors choose to elaborate on-- that's where they will stand out. In most books the first 3 chapters are often identical because the axiomatic setup and fundamental results that follow are so standardized. First you have linear spaces, then some topology, then the open/closed mapping theorems, uniform boundedness principle, and off to the races.

Comment: Second $\text{Om(nom)}^3$'s advice: Kreyzsig is excellent, and definitely covers computational aspects and real-world applications better than many higher-level texts like Lax.

Comment: Kreyzsig is outstanding for a beginner. I would read it first before going to Rudin.